# Unicode Characters wont work in snapcraft

Tags: snapcraft

When I try to use Unicode characters, for example € my app only prints the escape sequence. i.e. `\u20AC`. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What worked for me is setting the locale under apps in my snapcraft.yaml file to look like the following.

```
apps:
  <app-name>:
    environment:
      LC_ALL: C.UTF-8
```

If that doesn't work also try setting the base to `core18`